# Planned events in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, calendar

I would like to have an option in Outlook to send meeting invitations even though it is not yet clear that the meeting actually is held.

During the time where that is not yet clear, the time should be marked in the participants' calendars (e. g. the time is marked as "tentative")

As soon as I have the final confirmation that the meeting takes place, I would like to be able to send some kind of meeting update to the participants telling them that the meeting is held. The free/busy status in their calendars should then automatically change into "busy".

Currently I am working with the "tentative" state, where the participants mark the event as "tentative". But as soon as I send out an update changig the appearance of the event to "busy", I am informed that the participants have been informed accordingly, but their free/busy status for that event has not changed.
(I understand that it's not the purpose of this flag to indicate if a meeting takes place or not, but currently this would be the easiest approach for me...)

Does anyone have a similar scenario?
Does anoyone know how to get that done?
Is there support in Exchange 2010? In Exchange 2016?
Any hint would be highly welcome.

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior that the meeting status (Show as) won't be updated along with a meeting update sent by the organizer. As a workaround, it is suggested to cancel the previous meeting and send a new meeting request with the Show as status set to "Busy". 
Here is a thread discussing a similar thing in MS Technet forum:
[Updating an existing meeting request from Tentative to Busy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49b4c334-4474-40a9-ac48-beda266ad342/updating-an-existing-meeting-request-from-tentative-to-busy?forum=outlook)